# how to include custom libraries

Tags: ros, external-libraries, libraries, library, target-link-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have a library(in C++) and I can compile and use it without ROS. It's a TCP/IP communication library. I want to listen those msgs and publish/use them in ROS. I know how to modify the cpp file to publish those msgs. But I don't know how to compile all together in ROS. So far, I found that I need to include target_link_libraries in CMakeList.txt file, but could not get it working. Let's say, my library sitting in home/ros_workspace/my_lib how should I modify the CMakeList.txt file?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33069/how-to-include-custom-libraries/) by [ecalisgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2287/ecalisgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create your own library, like this:

ADD_LIBRARY( yourlibrary_name STATIC your_file_hpp_and_cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( yourlibrary_name libraries_needed_by_your_library )

create node with your library
rosbuild_add_executable(the_node_name src/file1.cpp ... src/filen.cpp )
target_link_libraries(the_node_name  yourlibrary_name)

or simply add everything in rosbuild_add_executable(.....

---

Originally posted by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1